# Apptentive custom data not being passed

Tags: android, apptentive

I am integrating Apptentive on Android. I am passing custom data to the Message Center but it is not display on the Apptentive website. This is my code

```
HashMap<String, String> customData = new HashMap<String, String>();

//add package name
customData.put("package", getPackageName()); 

//show message center
Apptentive.showMessageCenter(ViralPopup.this, customData);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Data sent in this manner is attached to the message that the user sends. If they don't send a message, then you won't see the custom data show up. If you do send a message, look at the actual message you receive in the conversation view on the server. The custom data should be visible on the message itself.

To view the custom data, you simply mouse over the message, and click "Show Custom Data".

[image]

Comment: I am testing this on my device and the custom data is not appearing in the message on the website. I am looking at the 'Custom Device Data' and 'Custom Person Data' sections.

Comment: The custom data is attached to the message. This method is intended for sending data that is associated with a message. There are other methods for sending custom data attached to the person or the device. Check out http://www.apptentive.com/docs/android/api/com/apptentive/android/sdk/Apptentive.html#addCustomDeviceData%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks for the picture. That help me locate the custom data.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding custom **message** data, which will only be sent alongside a successful Apptentive message.

You may want to instead add custom **person** or **device** data, which will be automatically added to that person's events in your dashboard:

`Apptentive.addCustomPersonData(context, "city", "Seattle");`

`Apptentive.addCustomDeviceData(context, "color", "red");`

Custom Data docs:
http://www.apptentive.com/docs/android/features/#custom-data